# Kernel panic not syncing with keyboard plugged in

Tags: kernel, keyboard

My Raspberry Pi won't boot with a keyboard plugged in. It is a wireless Logitech two-in-one keyboard, and it says:

> end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: By wireless you don't mean "bluetooth", do you? If this for sure only happens with the keyboard in, it is probably one of two things: 1) Not enough power, use at least a 2 amp supply, or 2) Driver glitch, which may happen if this is a highly non-standard keyboard.  *You could also try plugging the keyboard in **after** boot* to see what happens.  USB keyboards and mice can be hotplugged and unplugged and always work, except to the extent that they may cause a voltage drop on the A/B and brown the pi out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some information in *[NOOBS RaspBMC and a kernel panic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=47286)*, and there seems to be a solution. Check it out and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't do that unless you are on a system that really should use `mmcblk0p6` as the root filesystem.  On plain Raspbian that won't even exist.  On NOOBs it would represent one or another OS type.

Comment: It would be better if you summarised the possible solution(s) here (in your answer).